# Regex match with and without space

Tags: regex

I have text line like this:

```
This is not imrtant </span>12 Kg Vanilje Sukker</div> neither is this side
```

AND like this

```
This is not imrtant </span>12 Kg VaniljeSukker</div> neither is this side
```

(see the missing space between Vanilje & Sukker)

My regex look like this:

```
/<\/span>(.+)\s(.+)\s(.+?\s?.+)<\/div>/i
```

and output

(first example)

```
[1]: 12 Kg
[2]: Vanilije
[3]: Sukker
```

(second example)

```
[1]: 12
[2]: Kg
[3] VanilijeSukker
```

I want the second result each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
/<\/span>(.+?)\s(.+?)\s(.+?)<\/div>/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .+ makes the reg-exp adopt a greedy behavior. This is how you should limit the greediness on the first two memory patterns too.

```
<\/span>(.+?)\s(.+?)\s(.+?\s?.+)
```