# How to search a string with no spaces from source where the same string might have spaces in between? (using regex)

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, whitespace

So, the problem is hopefully explained concisely in the heading. I could always modify my csv source and delete all whitespace, but there are other reasons that make that a less desireable option.

So any ideas? Is this even possible with regex? I am using python 3.3 + regex as my languages.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I have to be able to automate the regex for a couple of thousand strings, so dont ask what the string is :D

Comment: Look at this link it would help you [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965991/regex-match-with-and-without-space)

Comment: Are you looking for _any_ string appearing both with and without space in your file? Or are you just searching occurrences of _a_ string that have _optional_ space? Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: I actually figured out a solution, I'm just cutting up the source into smaller temporary parts and stripping them of extra spaces for the regex check. A concrete example for this would be searching 'cd' from a source 'ab c d efg h i jl km n o p q rst u v w xyz'. I'm just cutting up the source to smaller pieces and stripping the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a regex pattern depending on the string you want to search for:

```
>>> import re
>>> def search_with_spaces(what, where):
...     return re.search(' *'.join(what), where)
... 
>>> search_with_spaces('cd', 'ab c d efg')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00696A68>
>>> search_with_spaces('cd', 'ab c d efg').group(0)
'c d'
>>> search_with_spaces('cd', 'ab cd efg').group(0)
'cd'
>>> search_with_spaces('cd', 'ab c   d efg').group(0)
'c   d'
```

Probably won't be best efficiency if the amount of different strings you're searching for is large, but should do the trick.